# Redirect Console.Write... Methods to Visual Studio's Output Window While Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, console-application

From a **Console Application** project in **Visual Studio**, I want to redirect `Console`'s output to the **Output Window** while debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing cout in Visual Studio 2005 output window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286/capturing-cout-in-visual-studio-2005-output-window)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change application type to Windows before debugging. Without Console window, Console.WriteLine works like Trace.WriteLine. Don't forget to reset application back to Console type after debugging.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I knew it was something easy. I must have done this at least five times.

Comment: I forgot, Alex Farber, YOUR AWESOME!

Comment: Moreover, don't forget to remove the System.Windows.Forms reference that is added when changing the project type.

Comment: "Don't forget to reset application back to Console type after debugging." I just did. LOL

Answer (score 19):

```
    class DebugWriter : TextWriter
    {        
        public override void WriteLine(string value)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
            base.WriteLine(value);
        }

        public override void Write(string value)
        {
            Debug.Write(value);
            base.Write(value);
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.Unicode; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG         
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Console.SetOut(new DebugWriter());   
#endif

            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
    }
```

** note that this is roughed together almost pseudo code. it works but needs work :) **

Comment: The problem with this approach is 1) it is code based 2) the output is not the same, and 3) a console window is still opened.

Comment: I do not remember specifically, but I was missing new lines. Probably because Console.WriteLine() use.

Comment: There was a bug where the WriteLine overload was using Debug.Write instead of Debug.WriteLine. I've edited.

Comment: I think it is best to override `public override void Write(char value)` as it seems to be called from all variations of Write, WriteLine, etc.  Inside it, only need `Debug.Write(value);` as the base function doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can change it to System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write();

Answer (score 3):

Note if you're using dkackman's method but you want to write the output to BOTH the console window and the debug window, then you can slightly modify his code like this:

```
class DebugWriter : TextWriter
{
    //save static reference to stdOut
    static TextWriter stdOut = Console.Out;

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
        stdOut.WriteLine(value);
        base.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        Debug.Write(value);
        stdOut.Write(value);
        base.Write(value);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.Unicode; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Trace.Write and use DebugView

Answer (score -2):

Actually, there is an easiest way: In the "Options" window of Visual Studio (from the Tools menu), go to "Debugging" then check the option "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window".

Comment: ctrl-alt-I brings up the intermediate window, but yeah it shows as empty.