# Having the output of a console application in Visual Studio instead of the console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

When doing a console application in Java with Eclipse, I see the output being put in a text box in the IDE itself, instead of having a console popping up like in Visual Studio. This comes in handy, as even after the program has exited, I can still make good use of the text that was written in it, as it doesn't get erased until I run it again. Is it possible to achieve anything like that with Visual Studio? I know that instead of doing

```
System.Console.WriteLine(str);
```

I can do

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

but it is not quite the same thing, as you get a lot of "junk" in the Output window, as all the loaded symbols and such.

Even better, is it possible to have everything done in the IDE itself, when you run your application, instead of having the console running?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Do you have a Test Results pane?

Comment: I've never noticed it. I'll check it. Should I have it?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In the Tools -> Visual Studio Options Dialog -> Debugging ->  Check the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window".

Comment: I've checked this checkbox but I still get a Console popup and nothing in the "Output" window (Debug, Test, Build,..) or the "Immediate Window".

Comment: @EvenLisle you need to change the application type to Windows Application as in [stolsvik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9615237/834521). The option mentioned in this answer was on by default for me in any case.

Comment: What does "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window" excactly mean? Use various contexts if you need to. I am confused by what is the "immediate window".

Comment: @TooTone The question clearly states for a "console application" and changing it to something else just for debugging purposes, where I cannot even **Console.ReadKey()** is just straight up ridiculous!

Comment: Only works with Debug.WriteLine(), does not work with Console.WriteLine() :(

Answer (score 56):

In the *Visual Studio* Options Dialog -> Debugging -> Check the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window". Then go to your project settings and change the type from "Console Application" to "Windows Application". At that point Visual Studio does not open up a console window anymore, and the output is redirected to the Output window in Visual Studio. However, you cannot do anything "creative", like requesting key or text input, or clearing the console - you'll get runtime exceptions.

Comment: I find this particularly clumsy.  What, I wonder, is the rationale behind this in VS?  It should be the ability of all modern day IDE's to have a panel within the IDE itself behave as the console for input and output.  (scratches head)

Comment: The question clearly states for a _"console application"_ and changing it to something else just for debugging purposes, where I cannot even `Console.ReadKey()` is just straight up ridiculous!

Comment: Not sure why but when I tried to revert the `Output type` of my application back from Windows Application to Console then the console window is no where to be seen when I run my application. I'm able to debug the application and `Main` entry point is also getting hit. I also reverted the option setting mentioned in this post but to no avail. I'm using VS 2017 community edition. *I lost my console window* (sobbing).

Comment: For what it's worth, in VS 15.8.7 the only way I could get the output to redirect for a console app was to change it to a Windows app, and leave the Redirect box UNCHECKED. If I check the box, it does not display the output.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`System.Diagnostics.Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx)

Depending on what listeners you attach, trace output can go to the debug window, the console, a file, database, or all at once.  The possibilities are literally endless, as implementing your own TraceListener is extremely simple.

Comment: Yes, but what I want to know is if it is possible to just do it, without having to implement it by myself.

Comment: @devoured The Trace class outputs just to the debug window by default.  You only need to attach extra listeners (and there are several already written you can use) if you want to also see the output elsewhere.

Comment: I went to my Debug Options dialog and chose "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" to make the Trace output go to the Immediate window so it doesn't get all mixed up with the debug crap.

Comment: Showing an actual solution / example would be more useful

Answer (score 4):

It's time to check the latest release/s for Visual Studio, folks. The most suggested solution that did not work for some of you before might work now.

In Visual Studio 2017 (**Release Version 15.4.2** and above), going to `Tools > Options > Debugging > General > (Check Box) Redirect all Output Window text to Immediate Window` has worked for me.

Few Notes:

1. To see the Immediate Window, make sure that you are in **Debugging** mode.
2. There should now be 3 other debugging tools available at your disposal, namely, Call Stack, Breakpoints, and Command Window, as shown below:

[image]

Best wishes!

Comment: Tested in v15.9.4, doesn't work (not for a console application, at least).

Comment: Hmm. If you can share a screenshot of your configurations, I can try to replicate the issue on my end. Otherwise, you can share your solution if it's been resolved. Release notes for Visual Studio 15.9.4 is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#-visual-studio-2017-version-1594, you might find some helpful tips there depending on your environment.

**Visual Studio 2017 (Output Window) Documentation**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2017

Comment: Doublecheck that the project you're testing with was created as a "console application", not a "windows application".  Your approach works with a windows application, but that's not what the OP specified.

Comment: This seems to not work for Console project in VS2022

Answer (score 3):

You can try [VSConsole](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.VSConsole) which allow you to integrate its console window inside VisualStudio as dock panel at bottom. To use this you have to

- Add [VSCodeExtension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.VSConsole) to VisualStudio
- Add [VSCode NugetPackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VSConsole/) reference in your project.
- Add using Console = VSConsole.Console; as namespace reference in *.cs file
- change the Output type from Console Application to Windows Application to hide the main console window that pops up when you run your console application.

Then your application will use VSConsole.Console class insted of System.Console class.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using same methods on `Console` that are available in `Debug class` like `Console.WriteLine(string)` then in .net core you can add below line as your 1'st line in `program.cs` file.

```
global using Console = System.Diagnostics.Debug;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Now all your call for `Console.WriteLine(string)` are executed as `Debug.WriteLine(string)` in all *.cs files in project. At places where you want to explicitly use `console` methods like `Console.Readline()` then you have to replace it with  fully qualified class name `System.Console.ReadLine()`.

Now output from all your `Console.WriteLine(string)` is now visible in Visualstudio output window. You can further filter out noise in `output window` by selecting what type of messages you want to see in that window as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper application that you run instead of directly running your real app.  The wrapper application can listen to stdout and redirect everything to Trace.  Then change the run settings to launch your wrapper and pass in the path to the real app to run.

You could also have the wrapper auto-attach the debugger to the new process if a debugger is attached to the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that works for me, to work with console ability(ReadKey, String with Format and arg etc) and to see and save the output:

I write TextWriter that write to `Console` and to `Trace` and replace the `Console.Out` with it.

if you use  Dialog -> Debugging -> Check the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window" you get it in the Immediate Window and pretty clean.

my code:
in start of my code:

```
Console.SetOut(new TextHelper());
```

and the class:

```
public class TextHelper : TextWriter
{
    TextWriter console;

    public TextHelper() {
        console = Console.Out;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding => this.console.Encoding;

    public override void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg)
    {
        string s = string.Format(format, arg);
        WriteLine(s);
    }

    public override void Write(object value)
    {
        console.Write(value);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(value);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(object value)
    {
        Write(value);
        Write("\n");
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        console.WriteLine(value);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Note: I override just what I needed so if you write other types you should override more

Answer (score 0):

I know this is just another answer, but I thought I'd write something down for the new Web Developers, who might get confused about the "Change to a Windows Application" part, because I think by default an MVC application in Visual Studio 2013 defaults to an Output Type of Class Library.

My Web Application by default is set as an output type of "Class Library." You don't have to change that. All I had to do was follow the suggestions of going to Tools > Options > Debugging > Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window. I then used the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` suggestion by Joel Coehoorn above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can collect the output in a test result.

You can't supply input, but you can easily provide several tests with different command line arguments, each test collecting the output.

If your goal is debugging, this is a low effort way of offering a repeatable debugging scenario.

```
namespace Commandline.Test
{
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class CommandlineTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void RunNoArguments()
        {
            Commandline.Program.Main(new string[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding `System.Diagnostics.Debug` producing a lot of "junk" in the Output window:
You can turn that off by right clicking in the output window. E.g. there's an item "Module Load Messages" which you want to disable and an item "Program Output" which you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You have three possibilities to do this, but it's not trivial.
The main idea of all IDEs is that all of them are the parents of the child (debug) processes. In this case, it is possible to manipulate with standard input, output and error handler. So IDEs start child applications and redirect out into the internal output window. I know about one more possibility, but it will come in future

1. You could implement your own debug engine for Visual Studio. Debug Engine control starting and debugging for application. Examples for this you could find how to do this on learn.microsoft.com ([Visual Studio Debug engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/debugger/debug-engine?view=vs-2019))
2. Redirect form application using duplication of std handler for c++ or use Console.SetOut(TextWriter) for c#. 
   If you need to print into the output window you need to use Visual Studio extension SDK.
   Example of the second variant you could find on [Github](https://github.com/Nesviatypaskha/VsConsoleOutput).
3. Start application that uses  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (for printing into output) and than it will start child application. On starting a child, you need to redirect stdout into parent with pipes. You could find an example on MSDN. But I think this is not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need output from Console.WriteLine, and the  *Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window* does not function and you need to know the output of Tests from the Integrated Test Explorer, **using NUnit.Framework** our problem is already **solved at VS 2017**:

Example taken from C# In Depth by Jon Skeet:
[image: Example taken from C# In Depth by Jon Skeet]
This produce this output at Text Explorer:
[image: Task Explorer]

When we click on Blue Output, under Elapsed Time, at right, and it produces this:
[image: Standard Output]

***Standard Output*** is our desired Output, produced by Console.WriteLine.

It functions for Console and for Windows Form Applications at VS 2017, but only for Output generated for Test Explorer at Debug or Run; anyway, this is my main need of Console.WriteLine output.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Sarel Foyerlicht's answer, the only way it work on my side is routing to debug output using this (complete) wrapper.

```
public class DebugTextWriter : StreamWriter
{
    public DebugTextWriter() : base(new DebugOutStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, 1024) { this.AutoFlush = true; }

    sealed class DebugOutStream : Stream
    {
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { Debug.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, offset, count)); }

        public override bool CanRead => false;
        public override bool CanSeek => false;
        public override bool CanWrite => true;
        public override void Flush() => Debug.Flush();

        public override long Length => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override long Position { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    };
}
```

which is utilized by rerouting via

```
System.Console.SetOut(new DebugTextWriter())
```