# Cannot get Console.Writeline to redirect to visual studio window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a program that just does `Console.WriteLine("abc");`

I would like to get that output to be within the visual studio window rather than in a cmd window that pops up.

I have tried what was suggested  [at this SO link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso) but it hasn't helped.

I have done File..New...Project..Visual C#.. Windows.. Console Application
[image]

And i've gone to debug..options and settings..
then ticked "Redirect all output text to the intermediate window"

[image]

[image]

None of that helps though!

The command window still appears when I click Start / Hit F5.

Really i'm looking for a cmd window to not appear and output just to be redirected to the output window

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ADDED**

It has been suggested that I check the Intermediate window (Ctrl-Alt-I)

It is coming up as Blank.

It has been suggested that I Go to project..properties and change the type of the application to a Windows Application.

When I do that, I get no cmd window come up (fine). But I don't see any cmd output in the output window, or the intermediate window. And the intermediate window is empty.

**Here is for the case where I have the cmd window coming up (so when the type is set to console)**

Notice the output window doesn't have the cmd output, and the intermediate window is empty.

[image]

[image]

**Here is the case for when I have set the type to Windows application so no cmd window comes up**

ah I see it in the output window.. I might've had to scroll a bit.. or clear it first to make it clearer. nothing in the intermediate window, but I see in the output window.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same question you linked to, there's another answer. You need to change the project from a Console Application to a Windows application, apart from the steps you carried out above.

[image]

This causes the output to go to the Output window:

[image]

Comment: I tried that and I then get no cmd window come up and no output in the output window

Comment: I just tried it, it works. The cmd window doesn't come up (which is what you want) and you can't interact with the application, but you do get output in the output window.

Comment: Otherwise if you still want the cmd window use System.Diagnostics.Trace instead of Console.WriteLine

Comment: When I change the type to winows application then I get no cmd prompt up(fine), but no cmd  output the output window or the intermediate window. And the intermediate window is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. Make sure you've ticked the Redirect to Immediate Window option, and changed the project type. It works like this - I've just added a screenshot to my answer. Check that the "Show output from" dropdown is set to Debug.

Comment: Right, that's it - you're looking at the immediate window, not the Output window.

Comment: thanks.. funny I can't get it to redirect to the intermediate window though given that I checked that box but anyhow.. yep I see it now in the output window, thanks. I guess I was expecting it to be at the bottom of the output window.

Comment: That option is pretty misleading (it says that it redirects to immediate window, but it doesn't), and I'd like to know why it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a linefeed to the string with \n.
This typically happens when you don't add line feed.
Text is stored in a line buffer before actual printing.

That could be different between Console and Visual Studio Window?

Comment: The WriteLine puts a \n in there anyway, but I tried adding a \n to the string, and still nothing in the output window, or the intermediate window