# Visual Studio 2013: Redirecting console output to Visual Studio Output Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cout

I am used to Eclipse CDT where the output of a program (using cout) is written to the "Console" window inside Eclipse. 
[image]

Now I switched to Visual Studio 2013. When creating a simple C++ "Console Application" like

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {  
       cout << "hello world" << endl;   cin.get();  return 0; 
    }
```

the application is "run in the Dos console", i.e. when I press "Run" Visual Studio opens a small Dos window and runs the program from there. As a result, the system input and output has to be done over the Dos window as well.

My question is the following: Is it somehow possible to redirect the input and output to the Visual Studio Output window (or any other perspective/view inside Visual Studio)? I am just getting annoyed by the fact there is no integrated console...[image]

So basically what I want to achieve is to see the "hello world" output in the "Output" Window of Visual Studio. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks

Comment: See this answer maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way of doing that is to use `OutputDebugString(str);`

Comment: Jop I saw this approach as well. But I am rather looking for a way to redirect the output than to use another method call. I will accept your answer if it turns out that there is no other way to achieve this. Upvoted to give you credit.

Comment: There is also macro called TRACE() that is widely used. It does call OutputDebugString(str); as well. It is defined in DEBUG build only.

Comment: I see. But there is definitely no way to somehow configure Visual Studio to do this without any code? Thx for the support.