# Is there a method of having the output of a local windows debugger to be integrated within the interface of visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have been coding in visual studio for a long time but I don't know how to integrate the command prompt window for the local windows debugger, with the visual studio interface itself.

I have seen there are other programs where the output is displayed within the interface of the program itself.

Programs such as NetBeans.

Is this a possible thing in c++?, as I am getting tired of going back and forth in the output executioner file for the local windows debugger.

Comment: Do you want to print the program's "output", or just some logging information? If it's the later, it's just a matter of using `OutputDebugString()`

Comment: I want to print the programs output, but I also want to have the capability to send information back in the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having the output of a console application in Visual Studio instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso)

Comment: Ive already tried the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window" but it doesnt work.. I have ticked the option for this. I was told to do something else which was Then go to your project settings and change the type from "Console Application" to "Windows Application", but I cant find this.. I dont know where the project setting is and where to find console application