# Start Console Application in Integrated Command Window

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Let's say you open a brand new solution for a "Console App (.NET Framework)", inside of which you put a simple Hello World line, and a `Console.ReadLine()` so it won't quit immediately.

When you hit Start, a new command window will open on top of your existing Visual Studio 2019 window, such that you now have two windows. I'm looking to make the program I'm compiling run instead in the integrated Command Window tab of Visual Studio, to reduce the number of things going on on my screen. I'd prefer to manage the project completely within Visual Studio and not have to keep minimizing/restoring the command window.

Below is a poor Photoshop of what I'm looking for. Is this possible?
[image]

Update: Regarding a comment to change the project type to "Windows Application":

1. There is no project type with that exact name in Visual Studio 2019 (with the ".NET desktop environment" package installed)
2. I want my project to be a Console Application anyway, just executed within VS2019 instead of in an external PowerShell window. The product that I need to deliver must be a Console Application.

[image]

Comment: You could use the "Execute in Interactive" command (Ctrl+E,Ctrl+E): https://dailydotnettips.com/execute-in-interactive-send-to-c-interactive-window-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 0):

### See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso)

### What to do:

Go into **Tools > Visual Studio Options > Debugging > Check the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window" checkbox.**

You will also need to **change the project type to "Windows Application."**

If this is not what you are looking for, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Without changing the project type, the console still popped up. Looking in the project types list, I don't see any specifically named "Windows Application" - can you tell me what project type should be used to get this to work, via Visual Studio 2019 (fully updated at the time of commenting)?

Comment: where you can select your project as being a "Console Application", now select "Windows Application". It should be in the projects settings found inside the Solution

Comment: See my edit to the question - there is no "Windows Application" option, but regardless, I want to use a Console Application project type

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a way of doing it with console. What are you doing that has to be console though?