# How to get the "Output" tab in visual studio to display the output?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have some code (not related), which I'm running in Visual Studio. However, when I run it, it always runs in Command Line (which is fine), but I would also like it to display the output in the Output bar in Visual Studio, so that I can work on my code at the same time.

[image]

(On the left is my code, the middle is the Command Line, and the Output bar is (empty) on the right.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe some of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2542599/3797799 apply to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're looking for the Output panel, but instead the integrated terminal. That way it will work just like in Command Prompt because that's what you will be using from within VS Code. Plus the Output panel won't work for what you're after since it can't take input.