# Print the output of a C++ program in internal console in Visual Studio, instead of default external cmd window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd, console

I tried the solution suggested in the question [Having the output of a console application in Visual Studio instead of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542599/having-the-output-of-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-instead-of-the-conso), but none of them are working. Please help.

Comment: iirc, that is not supported.  There may be a VS extension to support it, like **VsConsoleOutput** (which I haven't tried myself).

Comment: Look up `OutputDebugString()`.  This may only work in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59621834/make-output-of-console-application-directly-into-visual-studio-and-not-external) carefully.

About how to use `OutputDebugString()` I wrote a sample for your reference.

```
int main()
{

    char buffer[100];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "check it out: %s\n", "this is a sample");
    OutputDebugStringA(buffer);
    return 0;

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It is not mandatory to print output in internal console, if one has to do too much extra work. Is it possible to make some setting in Visual Studio IDE so that it works with simple "cout" ??

Comment: @Pawan Kumar , I am sorry to tell you that the current function of VS cannot realize this idea.