# Include a console window, down besides the intermidiate window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Using Visual Studio I would like a console window inside the IDE, instead of the program opens a new console window, when it runs.

Do anyone one know if this feature exists and how to enable it?

uhh, dont know why I have to write what I tried... I tried googling it, and I did not find a solution of how to enable this feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you run a console application in the Visual Studio output window, instead of opening a new command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194436/how-do-you-run-a-console-application-in-the-visual-studio-output-window-instead)

Comment: I'm afraid not. These answers are fairly old, and it seems some change has been made to the IDE, since then.